changing layout from LTR to RTL in React
I am looking for help to change layout from LTR to RTL When user clicked on Arabic language, what also i am looking for is keeping RTL layout whenever he selected Arabic language, and in case if he changes to English then the layout will change to RTL. Here is the code of Localization.tsx:


import { useRef, useState } from 'react';

// material-ui
import { useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { Box, ClickAwayListener, Grid, List, ListItemButton, ListItemText, Paper, Popper, Typography, useMediaQuery } from '@mui/material';

// project-imports
import MainCard from 'components/MainCard';
import IconButton from 'components/@extended/IconButton';
import Transitions from 'components/@extended/Transitions';
import useConfig from 'hooks/useConfig';

// assets
import { LanguageSquare } from 'iconsax-react';
// types
import { I18n, ThemeMode } from 'types/config';

// ==============================|| HEADER CONTENT - LOCALIZATION ||============================== //

const Localization = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const matchesXs = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('md'));

  const { i18n, onChangeLocalization } = useConfig();

  const anchorRef = useRef<any>(null);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const handleToggle = () => {
    setOpen((prevOpen) => !prevOpen);
  };

  const handleClose = (event: MouseEvent | TouchEvent) => {
    if (anchorRef.current && anchorRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
      return;
    }
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const handleListItemClick = (lang: I18n) => {
    onChangeLocalization(lang);
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const iconBackColorOpen = theme.palette.mode === ThemeMode.DARK ? 'secondary.200' : 'secondary.200';
  const iconBackColor = theme.palette.mode === ThemeMode.DARK ? 'background.default' : 'secondary.100';
  return (
    <Box sx={{ flexShrink: 0, ml: 0.5 }}>
      <IconButton
        color="secondary"
        variant="light"
        aria-label="open localization"
        ref={anchorRef}
        aria-controls={open ? 'localization-grow' : undefined}
        aria-haspopup="true"
        onClick={handleToggle}
        size="large"
        sx={{ color: 'secondary.main', bgcolor: open ? iconBackColorOpen : iconBackColor, p: 1 }}
      >
        <LanguageSquare variant="Bulk" size={26} />
      </IconButton>
      <Popper
        placement={matchesXs ? 'bottom-start' : 'bottom'}
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorRef.current}
        role={undefined}
        transition
        disablePortal
        popperOptions={{
          modifiers: [
            {
              name: 'offset',
              options: {
                offset: [matchesXs ? 0 : 0, 9]
              }
            }
          ]
        }}
      >
        {({ TransitionProps }) => (
          <Transitions type="grow" position={matchesXs ? 'top-right' : 'top'} in={open} {...TransitionProps}>
            <Paper sx={{ boxShadow: theme.customShadows.z1, borderRadius: 1.5 }}>
              <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClose}>
                <MainCard border={false} content={false}>
                  <List
                    component="nav"
                    sx={{
                      p: 1,
                      width: '100%',
                      minWidth: 200,
                      maxWidth: 290,
                      bgcolor: theme.palette.background.paper,
                      [theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: {
                        maxWidth: 250
                      }
                    }}
                  >
                    <ListItemButton selected={i18n === 'en'} onClick={() => handleListItemClick('en')}>
                      <ListItemText
                        primary={
                          <Grid container>
                            <Typography color="textPrimary">English</Typography>
                            <Typography variant="caption" color="textSecondary" sx={{ ml: '8px' }}>
                              (UK)
                            </Typography>
                          </Grid>
                        }
                      />
                    </ListItemButton>
                    <ListItemButton selected={i18n === 'ar'} onClick={() => handleListItemClick('ar')}>
                      <ListItemText
                        primary={
                          <Grid container>
                            <Typography color="textPrimary">عربي</Typography>
                            <Typography variant="caption" color="textSecondary" sx={{ ml: '8px' }}>
                              (Arabic)
                            </Typography>
                          </Grid>
                        }
                      />
                    </ListItemButton>
                    <ListItemButton selected={i18n === 'fr'} onClick={() => handleListItemClick('fr')}>
                      <ListItemText
                        primary={
                          <Grid container>
                            <Typography color="textPrimary">français</Typography>
                            <Typography variant="caption" color="textSecondary" sx={{ ml: '8px' }}>
                              (French)
                            </Typography>
                          </Grid>
                        }
                      />
                    </ListItemButton>
                    <ListItemButton selected={i18n === 'ro'} onClick={() => handleListItemClick('ro')}>
                      <ListItemText
                        primary={
                          <Grid container>
                            <Typography color="textPrimary">Română</Typography>
                            <Typography variant="caption" color="textSecondary" sx={{ ml: '8px' }}>
                              (Romanian)
                            </Typography>
                          </Grid>
                        }
                      />
                    </ListItemButton>
                    <ListItemButton selected={i18n === 'zh'} onClick={() => handleListItemClick('zh')}>
                      <ListItemText
                        primary={
                          <Grid container>
                            <Typography color="textPrimary">中国人</Typography>
                            <Typography variant="caption" color="textSecondary" sx={{ ml: '8px' }}>
                              (Chinese)
                            </Typography>
                          </Grid>
                        }
                      />
                    </ListItemButton>
                  </List>
                </MainCard>
              </ClickAwayListener>
            </Paper>
          </Transitions>
        )}
      </Popper>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Localization;



And here is the RTL layout code:


import { useEffect, ReactNode } from 'react';

// material-ui
import { CacheProvider } from '@emotion/react';
import createCache, { StylisPlugin } from '@emotion/cache';

// third-party
import rtlPlugin from 'stylis-plugin-rtl';

// project-imports
import useConfig from 'hooks/useConfig';

// types
import { ThemeDirection } from 'types/config';

// ==============================|| RTL LAYOUT ||============================== //

interface Props {
  children: ReactNode;
}

const RTLLayout = ({ children }: Props) => {
  const { themeDirection } = useConfig();

  useEffect(() => {
    document.dir = themeDirection;
  }, [themeDirection]);

  const cacheRtl = createCache({
    key: themeDirection === ThemeDirection.RTL ? 'rtl' : 'css',
    prepend: true,
    stylisPlugins: themeDirection === ThemeDirection.RTL ? [rtlPlugin as StylisPlugin] : []
  });

  return <CacheProvider value={cacheRtl}>{children}</CacheProvider>;
};

export default RTLLayout;




You should accomplish this with CSS and not logic. Use things like begin and end when aligning elements instead of left and right, and you should be fine.

To convert the layout from LTR to RTL in React when the user picks Arabic, alter the RTLLayout component to detect the language change and update the document orientation appropriately. Here's how you can accomplish it
import { useEffect, ReactNode } from 'react';
import { CacheProvider } from '@emotion/react';
import createCache, { StylisPlugin } from '@emotion/cache';

// third-party
import rtlPlugin from 'stylis-plugin-rtl';

// project-imports
import useConfig from 'hooks/useConfig';

// types
import { ThemeDirection } from 'types/config';

// ==============================|| RTL LAYOUT ||============================== //

interface Props {
  children: ReactNode;
}

const RTLLayout = ({ children }: Props) => {
  const { themeDirection, i18n } = useConfig(); // Assuming `i18n` holds the currently selected language

  useEffect(() => {
    // Update document direction based on the selected language
    document.dir = i18n === 'ar' ? ThemeDirection.RTL : ThemeDirection.LTR;
  }, [i18n]);

  const cacheRtl = createCache({
    key: themeDirection === ThemeDirection.RTL ? 'rtl' : 'css',
    prepend: true,
    stylisPlugins: themeDirection === ThemeDirection.RTL ? [rtlPlugin as StylisPlugin] : []
  });

  return <CacheProvider value={cacheRtl}>{children}</CacheProvider>;
};

export default RTLLayout;

